# pass Node JS variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to show the entire DB file on the client side.

I have a DB file and it is connected from python script and the python script is connected with my Node JS server.
I would like to make a table on html file using javascript.
I am not sure this is a proper way to pass a Node JS variable to javascript.

When I do console.log(data[0]); in the javascript file, I thought it is supposed to print out the first line of the data variable but it only prints out the first letter of the entire data variable.

I want to receive the data variable as an object or array from javascript, not as letters, but I do not know how to.

Below is my part of server.js

```
app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    var options = {
        mode: 'json',
        pythonPath:'',  
        pythonOptions:['-u'],
        scriptPath:'',
        args: []
    };
    PythonShell.PythonShell.run('dbShow.py', options, function(err, results) {
        if(err) throw err;
        const headings = ['Name','SSN','State'];
        res.render(__dirname + '/data.html',{headings:headings,data:results[0]});
    });
});
```

Below is my part of javascript code inside of html file.

```
<script>
    var data = "<%= data %>";
    var headings = "<%= headings %>";
    document.write("<table>");
    for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        document.write("<tr>");
        for(let j=0;j<headings.length;j++) {
            document.write("<td>"+data[i][j]+"</td>");
        }
        document.write("</tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sets `data` (client-side) to a string literal:

```
var data = "<%= data %>";
```

If the *server-side* `data` variable is known to be a JavaScript object or array, and wrapping it in quotes effectively makes it JSON, don't wrap it in quotes:

```
var data = <%= data %>;
```

Or parse the JSON

```
var data = JSON.parse("<%= data %>");
```

Which could be useful if the server-side `data` might be empty for example.  Or could at least produce a more meaningful error message for such cases rather than a JavaScript syntax error.

But as part of your debugging effort, the very first thing you'll want to do is look at the client-side page source and see what these lines are actually outputting.  If it's not valid JavaScript or JSON, you're going to want to address that.

Comment: var data = "<%= data %>";
var data = <%= data %>;
var data = JSON.parse(<%= data %>);
var data = JSON.parse("<%= data %>"); I tried four of them but it says SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: or SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string but when I check the type of results from the server side in node js, it is saying that it is an object.

Comment: @OnamKwon: So then what is the actual syntax you’re outputting?  Again, your first debugging step here is to look at the actual page source in the browser and see what your resulting JavaScript code is.  If the output isn’t what you expect then the problem isn’t in the JavaScript like you’re assuming, but in how you generate it.  For example, if the line of code you’re showing is exactly what you see in the browser page source then you’re never actually outputting the data to JavaScript.